# ¿Qué sobrecarga más un servidor a la hora de llamar imágenes en php?

Tags: php, imagen, servidor

andamos actualizando una web en PHP que recibe muchas visitas ya que es un grupo de servicios y hablamos de alrededor 200000-300000 visitas al mes.

Nos gustaría saber si a la hora de llamar a las imágenes de una página, que contiene una galería, es mejor tener thumbsnails de las mismas guardadas en servidor (ocupando el consiguiente espacio en disco duro) o es mejor generarlas en tiempo real con alguna clase enviándoselas al navegador del visitante, obviamente cargando el procesador del server.

Comment: pasarlas a diagramas vectoriales

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitivamente tienes que tener thumbnails para la galería. Cargar la imagen en tamaño real y redimensionar por CSS es ineficiente.

Habiendo dicho eso, si tu pregunta es "*genero el thumbnail de las imágenes al vuelo o las guardo en el servidor y las sirvo como estáticos*" la respuesta es claramente que el tiempo de carga de la página va a ser mucho más rápido si los thumbnail son estáticos. Desde la experiencia de usuario eso es un cambio muy notorio.

La generación de los thumbnails, si acaso se hace al subir una imagen, es un proceso que ocurre una sola vez. La generación al vuelo ocurre N veces por cada visita. El servidor va a colapsar por memoria y cpu.

El almacenamiento es barato. El uso de CPU y memoria es caro. No hay donde perderse en esto.

Sin embargo, tienes que tener en cuenta que **tu proyecto debe estar sujeto a control de versiones**, y por lo mismo tienes que buscar una manera de que las imágenes subidas y sus thumbnails también queden en control de versiones (e.g. github) o de lo contrario se perderán si haces un deploy a otra máquina. Una posible solución sería subir las imágenes a otro sitio (por ejemplo Amazon S3) y servirlas desde ahí, o si no tener un cron en el servidor que periódicamente comitee y pushee esos estáticos.

Comment: Cuando decía generar en tiempo real las imágenes usando una clase me refiero por ejemplo usando mthumb.php que te crea los thumbs en tiempo real cuando el cliente llama a la página. Pero con lo que has indicado me queda claro, un saludo y gracias.

Answer (score 1):

La idea de los thumbnails es la mejor. Siendo tanto el tamaño y la calidad menor que la original puede ser entre un 60-90% menos pesado dependiendo de la compresion, por lo que la carga va a ser mayor.

**Desde mi punto de vista**, la carga de la pagina es lo mas importante, invertir en espacio es mucho mas barato que perder usuarios por problemas de carga.

[Google: 53% of mobile users abandon sites that take longer than 3 seconds to load](https://www.soasta.com/blog/google-mobile-web-performance-study/)